# In vuetify, radio is not shown

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

With `vuetify`, after adding a simple radio, the radio is not shown, only the labels shown.

---

### Code

template:

```
<v-app height="100%">
  <v-radio-group v-model="radios">
    <v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-2"></v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
</v-app>
```

script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        radios: 'radio-1',
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

---

Any idea?

---

### @Update - Solution

It's the css file issue, in `index.html`, it's fixed after changing following line

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">`

to:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">`

And, I also run `yarn add @mdi/font -D` to install the font file, which is specified in `src/plugins/vuetify.js` *(not
 sure is this necessary though)*:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
});
```

**BTW:**

- I figured this out by re-add the vuetify plugin, and check `git diff`.
- And, it seems needs to restart the app to see the difference? Stop the application first, then `npm start` or `yarn start`.
- I was misled by the guide from vuetify's github's readme file.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/selection-controls/usage.vue), the radios model needs to hold a number.

Comment: @tomerpacific Tried that, still the same.

Comment: did you try copy and pasting the example code from Github and seeing if that works?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, both radio & checkbox are not shown, but on hover, there are some kinda of effects, so seems due to some image or css missing?

Comment: Do you have anything else in your code that might be causing this issue? Are any other Vue elements being shown correctly?

Comment: @tomerpacific Buttons are shown correctly, and the `v-switch` from the example you provided is also shown correctly, just the radio & checkbox not shown.

Comment: @tomerpacific It's the css file issue, I have updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: my index.html was lacking the stylesheet. Added it and voila, problem solved. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown here is correct. I checked it on my project. It shows the radio buttons just like:

[image]

So you issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding material icons link to html didn't help. In fact radio buttons accept icons as a Prop. So if we use already some icons in the app, like @mdi, it can be attached like this

```
<v-radio
  v-for="(lang, index) in languages"
  :key="index"
  :label="lang.name"
  :value="lang.locale"
  off-icon="mdi-radiobox-blank"
  on-icon="mdi-radiobox-marked"
  class="language__radio"
></v-radio>
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was much more simple but can be easily overlooked as a result. I had a css rule somewhere that affected all icon elements. Ensure this isn't happening. To solve, I targeted that specific class for that icon element as such.

html

`<i class="dashboard-home-arrow-up />`

css

`i.dashboard-home-arrow-up { /* styles here */}`